# Google Analytics - flagging PII/NPI (personally identifiable information & non-public information)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics

Can you set up alerts in Google Analytics to flag potential PII/NPI such as name, email address, billing address, billing details etc.? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

First I have do say I do not understand the downvote(s). For example I have seen applications with user logins where a full name was part of the page title - combined with time based dimensions that gave profile that say which user looked at what page at what time, and that would be clearly illegal. Even worse I have seen a case where security tokens were transmitted to GA that allowed access to secured resources. So clearly accidental transmission of PII to Google Analytics is a real thing.

Unfortunately there is not much you can do about it. You can either do a custom report with relevant dimensions and have it sent to you for a manual audit, or pull them via the API and have them programmatically examined via regular expressions that look for patterns like e-mail addresses etc. But by the time you can do that it is already to late, the data will already be permanently recorded in the GA property.

You have to stop this before the data is collected - if at all possible already in the website (via form validation etc), or use Google Tag Manager with custom javascript variables with validation rules, or filters in the analytics view (the latter being cumbersome and not very promising for this purpose).

The good news is that GA will not suddendly start to track PII on it's own. So you only need to check if your GA account tracks PII when you set up the account. Collect a few days data, validate that everything is okay, make changes as necessary and after all flaws are straightened out copy the view to start data collection from scratch and drop the old view if it contains PII.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. I appreciate the detail.

I agree that websites should not be sending PII to GA in the first place and I have seen PII data being sent through URLs many times.

Unfortunately I am not in direct contact with the developers and there are times where GA PII is not considered upfront in the development process. 

Even though it is a reactive approach, at the very least I need to be informed if changes are made that lead to PII leaks in GA. I will trying setting up custom reports and alerts.